# 6 Permissions added out of nowhere?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I generated a signed apk today of one of my apps and what I uploaded it on my Google's developer console it said that I have added 6 additional permissions like this:
[image]

And the permission that I have in my manifest file are only those:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I have recently updated some of the libraries that I use + I migrated to android v23 from 22. Is it possible that this change caused the additional permissions? 
These are the libraries that I use:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
//Two libaries needed for the material design dialogs
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
//FAB action button libary
compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
//custom text view to apply custom font easily
compile 'com.ctrlplusz.anytextview:library:1.2'
}
```

Comment: [something to read](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) while waiting for an answer :)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at :)

Comment: It seems to be what @0X0nosugar said. You have imported many external projects.

Comment: I figured the problem! When I was changing the versions of play services I removed the "ads" by mistake so it imported the whole library and that added the unwanted permissions. I wanted only the ads like that:
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0' 


So making this change fixed my problem: compile